# Developing an app for ios i'm supposed to support fast or slow connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

Strange question i know. I'm developing an app for ios for a target being the visitors of a commercial centre. The app provide an internal updating system, using an xml system, that for a long list of reasons works differently in the case of slow or fast response of the net. The difference stands in different type of malfunctioning of the ui, and i only can choose to have a better performance in the case the user have a slow connection OR a fast one, for the two solution (one for the problem on the fast case, one for the slow case) for the issue i have, involve one the presence of malfunctioning in the other case.
In this case, i'm supposed to favor users who belong a fast or slow connection and why?

Edit: I'll try to explain the problem. I have a view that need to be updated via xml. When i launch the view, the simple fact i try to access the xml to control if the update needs to be done, takes time. I added an activity indicator, but it doesn't work fine for, as the net gets slower, it seems to take more time to the activity indicator to show, with the result the user have to time to think the app is frozen, try to touch button he has not to touch (that will not work and make him think the app doesn't work) and so on. So i used performSelectorInBackground in order to add the activity indicator as fast i can and it works fine in the SLOW connection case. In the FAST connection case, the activity appear so fast that it appears even if the control if the update must be done, due to the speed of the connection, takes near no time, causing it to show the activity indicator for a picosecond, giving an awful graphical effect that is to be avoided. To avoid the problem in the FAST case i added a

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.000001 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{ code to add the activity indicator; });
```

and, in this way, i do not have the graphical problem of the FAST case, but in the SLOW case the execution of the dispatch_after (i guess) slow down the showing of the activity indicator too much causing the impression that the app freezed. So my hands are tied and i don't know what it's to prefer.

Comment: I don't understand the issue at all, whether they have a slow or fast connection shouldn't matter. If they need to download something and process it, you show an activity indicator and stop them touching the app until its done. why would this be different for slow v fast ?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: Its better if you support the slow connections in that way you can get  both Fast and slow connection users and the performance is taken care of for both the users. instead if you would optimize your app for fast connections only then definitely you'll loose the slow connection users.

Comment: So its definitely better to optimize your app for slower connections. Hope you understand.

Comment: For even gmail freeze on slow connection, and i was guessing if an expert programmer has a valid reason to care less about users that have a slow connection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine what type of connection user has (Edge/3G or Wi-Fi) and perform different methods for each type of connection. Sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/index.html). Usually wi-fi is faster and cheaper, so you can provide your "fast code" for it.

P.S. I am still not sure what are you talking about. Perfomance? Difficult to give proper advice without some details, but still:

1) You can download needed stuff in background.

2) If it's about menus with images/videos/music - start with downloading list with titles, after that download media files. (like android market does on slow connections).

EDIT:
First of all, don't mix views and network tasks. All downloading should be done outside of the ViewController, in another thread.
You can download new XML each N minutes (or use if-modified in your request) and show it next time user tries to see the view. How often do you get new XMLs? It's important, maybe you can avoid downloading it at the same moment with UI drawining. Good luck!

Comment: This is a good idea, i'll explore it. I've updated the answer in order to explain the problem.

Comment: Otherwise, i can't do stuff in background for the thing i have to do, must be done at the time i continue with the code. The slowing code control if an update must be done and takes no time for fast connection and a few (seems so long!) seconds in the slow case.

Comment: sounds like you need to set the spinner spinning before you try and access the remote xml

Comment: i do it! The problem (i guess) is that the code slowing the whole situation (the call to the xml) must lay on the main thread, like all the operation on the ui, and so the activation of the spinner. So i call the operations in the right succession but the second slows the first and all get messed up. Moving the second (the activation of the spinner) on the background thread make the spinner starts immediately but... and it's too fast :D

Answer (score 1):

As the target is visitors of a commercial centre, you should always work with fast connection to give a better user experience .. user does not like to wait long time with a loading screen on the device .. but you should also tackle the negative scenario, i.e, slow connection. You need to determine an optimized time depending on requirement so that you need to show the loading screen for that particular time only and still, if the connection is slow, you can terminate the connection with a 'Try Again' message .